# How to build/run image which can run on any window OS version (Docker supported)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Window service written in .Net Core, running in Visual studio 2022 and want to run this on container, for this I have added the docker file and my Window OS version is window 10. container is working fine on my system.
Now I am pushing my code/image to Docker hub through Azure DevOps Pipeline by using the (window 2022) Agent. Image pushed to Docker hub and when I pulled that image on my system it says 'base OS version is not compatible with the image version' like that, and when I build/push my image from (window 2019)agent its pulled and working fine.
Problem statement is that, I need to run this image on different windows OS version like (2008, 2012, 2016, 2019, 2022) windows server how this can be fulfill my requirement.
my dockerfile is below

```
    #See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base

WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebSocketClientService/WebSocketClientService.csproj", "WebSocketClientService/"]
COPY ["S3DocumentSyncLib/S3DocumentSyncLib.csproj", "S3DocumentSyncLib/"]
COPY ["CommonChat/WSDataModel.csproj", "CommonChat/"]
COPY ["WebSocketClient/WebSocketClient.csproj", "WebSocketClient/"]
COPY ["websocket-sharp-core/websocket-sharp-core.csproj", "websocket-sharp-core/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebSocketClientService/WebSocketClientService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebSocketClientService"
RUN dotnet build "WebSocketClientService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebSocketClientService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebSocketClientService.dll"]
```

Comment: you might want to share your Dockerfile in the question as well

Comment: yes added now check

Comment: I believe you are required to build each Windows version separately, and ship as a multi platform image. There's no concept of a Windows image that works on all versions.

Comment: how we can create the docker file in VS for 2008, 2012, 2016, 2019, 2022 OS version and for each OS build.
and if I have  host OS version 21H2 19044.2728  and  VS created the Docker file for the version.. what if Host OS version is 21H2 20044.2728 so how I can create the Docker file in VS ?